# Connecting to ESP8266 from Android device using socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, dns, esp8266

I'm trying to connect to my ESP8266 on a local network via TCP socket initiated from Android. The IP address of ESP changes everytime I restart my router thereby I gave it "esp.local" hostname.

Is there any way to connect to the ESP directly from Android not via IP address but through local hostname?

Comment: Can you share your code of android and ESP8266 end of how you are connecting them ... I am also doing the same project where i need to transfer data to ESP from Android  but i am kinda stuck in it ...

Answer (score 0):

You will be in need of mDNS feature.

Read about it in [here](http://en.0wikipedia.org/index.php?q=aHR0cHM6Ly9lbi53aWtpcGVkaWEub3JnL3dpa2kvTXVsdGljYXN0X0ROUw).

Take a look how the things done in ESP side from [here](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/ESP8266mDNS).

Get the ESP8266 mDNS example from [here](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266mDNS/examples/mDNS_Web_Server/mDNS_Web_Server.ino).